# How to check if all the element in the list of one algebraic type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-platform

If I have following algebraic data type

```
type MyVal = Either String Int
```

and have a list containing element of type MyVal

```
ls = [Right 1, Right 2, Right 3]
xs = [Right 1, Left "error", Right 3]
```

now, I want write function to  find out that is my list having all the value of 'Right' then it should return True otherwise False.

In case of `ls` it will return True and for `xs` it will return False.

How can I do that?

I have tried using `all` function but could not able to use it correctly.

Comment: @Saurabhkukade Then it is a type alias instead of algebraic data type.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not to gainsay `all isRight` as a good answer to the question which was asked, I'd question the question, to some extent. What good is it to compute, as a `Bool`, whether all the `Either` values in a list are `Right`? What does it enable you to do? One answer is that it entitles you to strip the `Right` tags from the entire list, treating the whole as error free.

A more informative option might be to construct something of type

```
[Either String Int] -> Either String [Int]
```

so that instead of a mere `True` or `False`, you obtain all the `Int`s untagged or the message associated with the first pesky `Left`.

And there is a standard function which does this (and many other things besides). It exploits the fact that lists are a data structure with a standard traversal pattern and that `Either String` encodes a notion of error-managing computation with standard patterns of failure and success propagation. The type has already done the hard work. All you need to say is...

```
sequenceA
```

Comment: in other words, `isRight . sequenceA` returns true when its argument doesn't contain a `Left`.

Comment: Somewhat related: if you find yourself wanting to collect all of the errors encountered (I often do), and not just the first, there's the `validation` package. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the [**`isRight :: Either a b -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:isRight) function to check if an `Either a b` value is a `Right x`.

So you can implement this with:

```
import Data.Either(isRight)

allRight :: Foldable f => f (Either a b) -> Bool
allRight = all isRight
```

This gives us the expected output:

```
Prelude Data.Either> allRight ls
True
Prelude Data.Either> allRight xs
False
```